# Citus - Possible to undo citus's create_time_partitions results?

Tags: postgresql, partition, database-partitioning, citus

I'm working on a database with Citus and I would like to know if it's possible to undo the results made by executing [create_time_partitions](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/stable/develop/api_udf.html#create-time-partitions). I know that it is possible to "undistribute" a distributed Citus table, but I want to be able to merge the partitions if I want to revert for any reason instead of deleting/dropping everything and re-creating the table from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

> but I want to be able to merge the partitions

We don't yet provide a function to alter time partitions but you should still be able to use regular ALTER TABLE commands to modify the partitions created by create_time_partitions() UDF.

I'd also suggest you to open a Github issue in Citus repo if you would like to make a feature request for this.